# How do i solve this problem: 'Martingale' - function call missing, open parenthesis expected?

Tags: mql5

Below is my first code:

```
// Trade
#include <Mql5Book\TradeHedge.mqh>
CTradeHedge Trade;
CPositions Positions;

// Price
#include <Mql5Book\Price.mqh>
CBars Bar;

// Money management
#include <Mql5Book\MoneyManagement.mqh>


// Trailing stops
#include <Mql5Book\TrailingStops.mqh>
CTrailing Trail;

// Timer
#include <Mql5Book\Timer.mqh>
CTimer Timer;
CNewBar NewBar;


// Indicators 
#include <Mql5Book\Indicators.mqh>
CiBollinger Bands;
CiRSI RSI;


//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Input variables                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

input ulong Slippage = 3;
input ulong MagicNumber = 43;
input bool TradeOnNewBar = true;

sinput string MM;   // Money Management
input bool UseMoneyManagement = true;
input double RiskPercent = 2;
input double FixedVolume = 0.1;

sinput string SL;   // Stop Loss & Take Profit
input int StopLoss = 0;
input int TakeProfit = 0;

sinput string TS;       // Trailing Stop
input bool UseTrailingStop = false;
input int TrailingStop = 0;
input int MinimumProfit = 0;
input int Step = 0; 

sinput string BE;       // Break Even
input bool UseBreakEven = false;
input int BreakEvenProfit = 0;
input int LockProfit = 0;

sinput string BB;       // Bollinger Bands
input int BandsPeriod = 20;
input int BandsShift = 0;
input double BandsDeviation = 2;
input ENUM_APPLIED_PRICE BandsPrice = PRICE_CLOSE; 

sinput string RS;   // RSI
input int RSIPeriod = 8;
input ENUM_APPLIED_PRICE RSIPrice = PRICE_CLOSE;

sinput string TI;   // Timer
input bool UseTimer = false;
input int StartHour = 0;
input int StartMinute = 0;
input int EndHour = 0;
input int EndMinute = 0;
input bool UseLocalTime = false;

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Global variables                                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

ulong glBuyTicket, glSellTicket;

enum Signal
{
    SIGNAL_BUY,
    SIGNAL_SELL,
    SIGNAL_NONE,
};

Signal glSignal;

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

int OnInit()
{
    Bands.Init(_Symbol,_Period,BandsPeriod,BandsShift,BandsDeviation,BandsPrice);
    RSI.Init(_Symbol,_Period,RSIPeriod,RSIPrice);

    Trade.Deviation(Slippage);
    Trade.MagicNumber(MagicNumber);
   return(0);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

void OnTick()
{

    // Check for new bar
    bool newBar = true;
    int barShift = 0;
    if(TradeOnNewBar == true) 
    {
        newBar = NewBar.CheckNewBar(_Symbol,_Period);
        barShift = 1;
    }


    // Timer
    bool timerOn = true;
    if(UseTimer == true)
    {
        timerOn = Timer.DailyTimer(StartHour,StartMinute,EndHour,EndMinute,UseLocalTime);
    }


    // Update prices
    Bar.Update(_Symbol,_Period);


    // Order placement
    if(newBar == true && timerOn == true)
    {

        // Money management
        double tradeSize;
        if(UseMoneyManagement == true) tradeSize = MoneyManagement(_Symbol,FixedVolume,RiskPercent,StopLoss);
        else tradeSize = VerifyVolume(_Symbol,FixedVolume);


        // Open positions
        ulong buyTickets[], sellTickets[];
        Positions.GetBuyTickets(MagicNumber, buyTickets);
        glBuyTicket = buyTickets[0];

        Positions.GetSellTickets(MagicNumber, sellTickets);
        glSellTicket = sellTickets[0];


        // Trade signal
        if(Bar.Close(barShift) < Bands.Lower(barShift) && RSI.Main(barShift) < 30) glSignal = SIGNAL_BUY;
        else if(Bar.Close(barShift) > Bands.Upper(barShift) && RSI.Main(barShift) > 70) glSignal = SIGNAL_SELL;


        // Open buy order
        if(glSignal == SIGNAL_BUY && Bar.Close(barShift) > Bands.Lower(barShift) && Bar.Close(barShift+1) <= Bands.Lower(barShift+1) && Positions.Buy(MagicNumber) == 0) 
        {
            if(glSellTicket > 0)
            {
               Trade.Close(glSellTicket);
            }

            glBuyTicket = Trade.Buy(_Symbol,tradeSize);

            if(glBuyTicket > 0)  
            {
                double openPrice = PositionOpenPrice(glBuyTicket);

                double buyStop = BuyStopLoss(_Symbol,StopLoss,openPrice);
                if(buyStop > 0) AdjustBelowStopLevel(_Symbol,buyStop);

                double buyProfit = BuyTakeProfit(_Symbol,TakeProfit,openPrice);
                if(buyProfit > 0) AdjustAboveStopLevel(_Symbol,buyProfit);

                if(buyStop > 0 || buyProfit > 0) Trade.ModifyPosition(glBuyTicket,buyStop,buyProfit);

                glSignal = SIGNAL_NONE;
            } 
        }

        // Open sell order
        if(glSignal == SIGNAL_SELL && Bar.Close(barShift) < Bands.Upper(barShift) && Bar.Close(barShift+1) >= Bands.Upper(barShift+1) && Positions.Sell(MagicNumber) == 0) 
        {
            if(glBuyTicket > 0)
            {
               Trade.Close(glBuyTicket);
            }

            glSellTicket = Trade.Sell(_Symbol,tradeSize);

            if(glSellTicket > 0)
            {
                double openPrice = PositionOpenPrice(glSellTicket);

                double sellStop = SellStopLoss(_Symbol,StopLoss,openPrice);
                if(sellStop > 0) sellStop = AdjustAboveStopLevel(_Symbol,sellStop);

                double sellProfit = SellTakeProfit(_Symbol,TakeProfit,openPrice);
                if(sellProfit > 0) sellProfit = AdjustBelowStopLevel(_Symbol,sellProfit);

                if(sellStop > 0 || sellProfit > 0) Trade.ModifyPosition(glSellTicket,sellStop,sellProfit);

                glSignal = SIGNAL_NONE;
            } 
        }

    }   // Order placement end

    // Get position tickets
    ulong tickets[];
    Positions.GetTickets(MagicNumber, tickets);
    int numTickets = ArraySize(tickets);


    // Break even
    if(UseBreakEven == true && numTickets > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numTickets; i++)
        {
           Trail.BreakEven(tickets[i], BreakEvenProfit, LockProfit);
        }
    }   
    // Trailing stop
    if(UseTrailingStop == true && numTickets > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numTickets; i++)
        {
           Trail.TrailingStop(tickets[i], TrailingStop, MinimumProfit, Step);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my MoneyMangement file:

```
#define MAX_PERCENT 10      // Maximum balance % used in money management


// Risk-based money management
double MoneyManagement(string pSymbol,double pFixedVol,double pPercent,int pStopPoints)
{
    double tradeSize;

    if(pPercent > 0 && pStopPoints > 0)
    {
        if(pPercent > MAX_PERCENT) pPercent = MAX_PERCENT;

        double margin = AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_BALANCE) * (pPercent / 100);
        double tickSize = SymbolInfoDouble(pSymbol,SYMBOL_TRADE_TICK_VALUE);

        tradeSize = (margin / pStopPoints) / tickSize;
        tradeSize = VerifyVolume(pSymbol,tradeSize);

        return(tradeSize);
    }
    else
    {
        tradeSize = pFixedVol;
        tradeSize = VerifyVolume(pSymbol,tradeSize);

        return(tradeSize);
    }
}


// Verify and adjust trade volume
double VerifyVolume(string pSymbol,double pVolume)
{
    double minVolume = SymbolInfoDouble(pSymbol,SYMBOL_VOLUME_MIN);
    double maxVolume = SymbolInfoDouble(pSymbol,SYMBOL_VOLUME_MAX);
    double stepVolume = SymbolInfoDouble(pSymbol,SYMBOL_VOLUME_STEP);

    double tradeSize;
    if(pVolume < minVolume) tradeSize = minVolume;
    else if(pVolume > maxVolume) tradeSize = maxVolume;
    else tradeSize = MathRound(pVolume / stepVolume) * stepVolume;

    if(stepVolume >= 0.1) tradeSize = NormalizeDouble(tradeSize,1);
    else tradeSize = NormalizeDouble(tradeSize,2);

    return(tradeSize);
}


// Calculate distance between order price and stop loss in points
double StopPriceToPoints(string pSymbol,double pStopPrice, double pOrderPrice)
{
    double stopDiff = MathAbs(pStopPrice - pOrderPrice);
    double getPoint = SymbolInfoDouble(pSymbol,SYMBOL_POINT);
    double priceToPoint = stopDiff / getPoint;
    return(priceToPoint);
}


//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Martingale Class                                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

#define HISTORY_DAYS 30

// Undocumented and untested - Use at your own risk
class CMartingale
{
    private:
        int ConsecutiveCount(string pSymbol, long pMagic, int pDays);
        int ConsWins, ConsLoss;

    public:
        enum ENUM_PROGRESSION {Martingale,Anti_Martingale};
        double Martingale(string pSymbol, long pMagic, double pBaseVol, double pMultiplier = 2, ENUM_PROGRESSION pProgress = Martingale);
};


double CMartingale::Martingale(string pSymbol, long pMagic, double pBaseVol, double pMultiplier = 2, ENUM_PROGRESSION pProgress = 0)
{
    double tradeSize;
    int consCount = ConsecutiveCount(pSymbol,pMagic,HISTORY_DAYS);

    if((pProgress == Martingale && ConsLoss > 0) || (pProgress == Anti_Martingale && ConsWins > 0))
    {
        tradeSize = pBaseVol * MathPow(pMultiplier,consCount);
    }
    else tradeSize = pBaseVol;

    tradeSize = VerifyVolume(pSymbol,tradeSize);

    return(tradeSize);
}


int CMartingale::ConsecutiveCount(string pSymbol, long pMagic, int pDays)
{
    long days = 86400 * pDays;
    HistorySelect(TimeCurrent() - days,TimeCurrent());

    int winCount = 0, lossCount = 0;

    for(int i=HistoryDealsTotal()-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        ulong ticket = HistoryDealGetTicket(i);
        long entry = HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_ENTRY);
        double profit = HistoryDealGetDouble(ticket,DEAL_PROFIT);
        long magic = HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_MAGIC);
        string symbol = HistoryDealGetString(ticket,DEAL_SYMBOL);

        if((entry == DEAL_ENTRY_OUT || entry == DEAL_ENTRY_INOUT) && magic == pMagic && symbol == pSymbol)
        {
            if(profit > 0 && lossCount == 0) winCount++;
            else if(profit < 0 && winCount == 0) lossCount++;
            else break;
        }
    }

    ConsWins = winCount;
    ConsLoss = lossCount;

    if(winCount > 0) return(winCount);
    else return(lossCount);
}
```

anytime i compile the top code it usually return the following:

```
'&&' - open parenthesis expected    MoneyManagement.mqh 103 30
'Martingale' - pointer to this function type is not supported yet   MoneyManagement.mqh 103 19
'Martingale' - function call missing, open parenthesis expected MoneyManagement.mqh 103 19
'Martingale' - function call missing, open parenthesis expected MoneyManagement.mqh 103 19
```

line 103 in the MoneyManagement file is: `if((pProgress == Martingale && ConsLoss > 0) || (pProgress == Anti_Martingale && ConsWins > 0))`

what is amazing is that it was compiling before but is no longer compiling now. will appreciate if this is solved. i did not change anything from the time it was compiling and this time when it refuse to compile

Comment: Are you sure that you've provided the full code? MoneyManagement file compiles without any problems, CMartingale class is not used as I can see in either the main mq5 file nor in the functions above it in the MM file

Comment: Thank you Daniel. when i commented the CMartingale code in the MoneyManagement file and recompiled, it compiled now.